# Extracting date from the string with offset in different timezones bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have one String datatype from which i want to extract the datetime /timestamp and change into the datetime datatype . Below is the sample of data . I can find some with seconds and some without.It has different timezones also like Oslo, Germany with different offset 1, 2 . Can anyone guide me how to align all of them . I used split function to take that out but now the return type is array how to handle that ?

2015-09-02T10:44+02:00[Europe/XXXX]

2015-08-22T14:17:36+02:00[Europe/XXXX]

2020-05-08T15:00+02:00[Europe/YYYY]

Inputs are required.

Thankyou

Comment: I have a very quick solution if you can ignore the `seconds` part of your timestamps. Is it the case?

Comment: Thanks ! Unfortunately that's not my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE(COALESCE(
    SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%Ez', REGEXP_REPLACE(ts, r'\[.+\]', '')),
    SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Ez', REGEXP_REPLACE(ts, r'\[.+\]', ''))
  )) extracted_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Above assumes that yo always have offset portion but sometimes don't have seconds part in time portion. Obviously you can adjust to more cases in your table.

If to apply to sample data in your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '2015-09-02T10:44+02:00[Europe/Berlin]' ts UNION ALL
  SELECT '2015-08-22T14:17:36+02:00[Europe/Oslo]' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-05-08T15:00+02:00[Europe/Madrid]' 
)
SELECT ts,
  DATE(COALESCE(
    SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%Ez', REGEXP_REPLACE(ts, r'\[.+\]', '')),
    SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Ez', REGEXP_REPLACE(ts, r'\[.+\]', ''))
  )) extracted_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

output it

```
Row ts                                      extracted_date   
1   2015-09-02T10:44+02:00[Europe/Berlin]   2015-09-02   
2   2015-08-22T14:17:36+02:00[Europe/Oslo]  2015-08-22   
3   2020-05-08T15:00+02:00[Europe/Madrid]   2020-05-08
```

Comment: Did you have chance to try proposed solution?

Comment: Mikhail I didn't tried this as i did single line code to extract all which worked well to my requirement as i need zone also .

Comment: select XXXX,split(XXXX,'T')[offset(0)], SPLIT(XXXX,'+')[offset(0)] , REGEXP_EXTRACT(SPLIT(XXXX,'+')[OFFSET(1)], r"[+^[a-zA-Z]+\/+[+^[a-zA-Z]+]") as zone 
from YYYY      Consider XXXX is the column name and YYYY is the table name

Comment: it depends on actually what you expect to "extract" as date from this entry `'2015-09-02T01:44+02:00[Europe/Berlin]'`? Is just `2015-09-02` which does not take into account time-zone? it still might be correct depends on your use case / business rule

Comment: Yes you are correct so i split the to extract date and zones .Thanks anyways it was a great code .

Answer (score 0):

In order to offer another option and further contribute with the community. I have developed a solution using [BigQuery UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) with JavaScript, which is useful when you want to reuse your code or made some modifications.

I have divided the JavaScript UDF's into three parts:

1. ***datetime_func***: find a timestamp, retrieves a string with the timestamp but not the timezone
2. ***format_check***: check the formatting, if the timestamp has seconds or not
3. ***get_timezone*** : returns the timezone as string

Below is the code (already with sample data):

```
#extracting the timestamp
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  datetime_func (s string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE js AS '''

  var myRe =  new RegExp(/\\[.*\\]/,'g');
  date_str =s.replace(myRe,"");
  return [(date_str)];
''';

#checking if the timestamp has seconds or not
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  format_check (s string)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN
  LANGUAGE js AS '''

  if(s.length == 25){ 
  //if the date string has the seconds with 2 digits
    return true;
  }else {return false;}
''';

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  get_timezone (s string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE js AS '''

  var myre = new RegExp(/\\[.*\\]/);
  z = (s.match(/\\[(.*?)\\]/));
  return z[1];
''';

#extracting the date
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  date_func (s string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE js AS '''
  return s.slice(0,10);
''';


WITH data AS (
  SELECT '2015-09-02T10:44+02:00[Europe/Berlin]' time_data UNION ALL
  SELECT '2015-08-22T14:17:36+02:00[Europe/Oslo]' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-05-08T15:00+02:00[Europe/Madrid]' 
)
SELECT time_data as ts
        #getting the date and converting to date format
        ,PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',date_func(time_data)) as date

       #if true, format with seconds and formating as timestamp format
        ,IF(format_check(datetime_func(time_data)) = True,
         (PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Ez',datetime_func(time_data))), 
         (PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%Ez', datetime_func(time_data)))) as timestamp, 
         get_timezone(time_data) as zone

FROM data
```

And the output:

[image]

Notice in the code that it was necessary to convert the date and the timestamp from *String* to *DATE* and *TIMESTAMP*, respectively.

UPDATE:

In order to change the column name in your view, you need to do as following:

```
SELECT time_data NEW_COLUMN_NAME_0
        #getting the date and converting to date format
        ,PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',date_func(time_data)) as NEW_COLUMN_NAME_1

       #if true, format with seconds and formating as timestamp format
        ,IF(format_check(datetime_func(time_data)) = True,
         (PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Ez',datetime_func(time_data))), 
         (PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%Ez', datetime_func(time_data)))) as NEW_COLUMN_NAME_2, 
         get_timezone(time_data) as NEW_COLUMN_NAME_3

FROM data
```

I have tagged every column name as **NEW_COLUMN_NAME**, you can change the column's names replacing with the desired name. Besides that, regarding saving the query, you should follow the instructions provided in the documentation, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#writing_query_results). The easiest method is to configure the query settings and define a destination table : **More** > **Query Settings** *( as the image below, taken from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#writing_query_results)).*

[image]

Comment: Alexandre it works for me but if i want to add a column instead of sample data how would i need to change it?

Comment: Its a great code but i need to modify it with column name lets say yyyy is column name in the table and xxxx is the dataset name with zzzz is the table name . How will i change this in your query .

Comment: @PrincyKhandelwal, if you want to use your data, simply delete the block `WITH data AS(....)` then in your select statement use `from your_source_table`. Regarding changing the column names, in your select statement after the `AS` you should put the desired column name.

Comment: In order to change the table name, you will have to create another table to save your view, click on More (under the code editor in the BigQuery UI), Query setting, mark _Set a destination table for query results_, select your project, dataset and write your table name where the results of the query will be saved. Please, do no forget to accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Alexandre Moreas its a great solution but can you provide me  more details with column name and and table name to be added where in the code I tried but its giving me error .

Comment: @BITaxiEngineer, I have updated the answer with a more detailed explanation. Do you have any other doubts?